# DataGrid not triggering collection setter when a new item is added

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a data grid with two text columns and one checkbox column. Whenever a user manually enters values and tabs out to enter a new row, `ItemsSource` doesn't get updated (setter of the collection does not fire)

```
  <DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column" RowHeaderWidth="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters}" 
                                      CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" MinHeight="140" Style="{StaticResource ParametersDataGridStyle}"
                                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key}" Width="*"/>
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}" Width="*"/>
   <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Post parameter" Binding="{Binding IsPostParameter}" Width="Auto" />
   </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

What to do to make this in sync with the property? Should I implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` ? Should I do it in a separate collection class like in this example:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/C-Sharp-and-xaml-within-a-silverlight-2-context-inotifycollectionchanged-implementation-part-v/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to subscribe the collection at the event CollectionChanged. When the method is called, you'll have all information about the action done at the list. For example, element added or removed...

Comment: Still, that event never gets fired, so my handler never gets hit:

            Parameters.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler((x, y) =>
            {

            });

Answer (score 0):

You can check it over CollectionChanged event, Count of the collection changes when a new row is added

Xaml

```
 <DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column" RowHeaderWidth="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Parameters,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                      CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" MinHeight="140" 
                                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Key" Binding="{Binding Key,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Post parameter" Binding="{Binding IsPostParameter,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="Auto" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Code behind

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Parameters = new ObservableCollection<ParamaterClass>();
            Parameters.CollectionChanged += Parameters_CollectionChanged;
            ParamaterClass ParamaterClass = new ParamaterClass();
            ParamaterClass.Key = "Test1Key";
            ParamaterClass.Value = "Test1Value";
            ParamaterClass.IsPostParameter = true;

            Parameters.Add(ParamaterClass);
        }

        void Parameters_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            int count = Parameters.Count;
        }
```